# Fill hstore attribute in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, simple-form

I have an hstore attribute named `salary` to store `min` and `max` values. To fill this in active admin (+ simple_form gem), I wrote the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do
  permit_params :salary

  form do |f|
    f.simple_fields_for :salary do |salary|
      salary.input :min, label: 'Min Salary'
      salary.input :max, label: 'Max Salary'
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

This shows me the right form with `job[salary][min]` and `job[salary][max]` inputs but doesn't save them when updated/created.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`hstore` requires some special `ActiveAdmin` code to work on edit and creation. You will need to write a custom controller action. Something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do

  controller do
    def update
      unless params[:job][:min].empty?
        job = Job.find(params[:id])
        job.min = params[:job][:min]
        job.save
      end

      unless params[:job][:max].empty?
        job = Job.find(params[:id])
        job.max = params[:job][:max]
        job.save
      end

      # Call the default update action
      super
    end
  end

end
```

The above snippet is assuming that you are using something like

```
store_accessor :salary, :min, :max
```

to access your `hstore` properties on your `Job` model.